# What should I include in the .gitignore file for Swift playgrounds?

Tags: xcode, git, swift, gitignore, swift-playground

I want to use Git for versioning my playgrounds, but I am not sure which files should be ignored and which ones I should commit.

Currently I use following `.gitignore` file for playgrounds:

```
# Xcode user data
xcuserdata
```

What else should be there?

Comment: Is it just a repo with `.playground` files and resources? As far as I know `.playground` files are pretty self-contained so you shouldn't need much. Here's what I use for Xcode and Swift in general, but it's probably a bit overkill: https://www.gitignore.io/api/xcode,swift

Comment: @Pops Yes, just .playground file. Using ignore for full blown projects seems like overkill. So far I used playgrounds only for short pieces of code, but I want to use them for longer code experiments, and those justify use of VCS and it is quite possible that some experiments may live long enough so I would not want to commit unwanted files.

Comment: Well, it it's just `.playground` files then there shouldn't really be any unwanted files. Just a folder of the playgrounds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the official [github gitignore for Swift](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore#L28)

```
## Playgrounds
timeline.xctimeline
playground.xcworkspace
```

Comment: The `timeline.xctimeline` file can be useful to share when enabling "Show Result", little grey box to right of output values for a Swift statement. Unfortunately, when you enable "Show Result", this file then contains a full path to the `*.playground` container inside of which is the very same `timeline.xctimeline` file, and this leaks personal information such as macOS user ID. However, the path does not need to make sense if passed to someone else so it can be anonymized as long as the anchor information is not lost.

Answer (score 11):

Whether it is a normal project or playgrounds, it is convenient and useful to use one of the standard `.gitignore` files for Swift. From the terminal `cd` into your project root folder (the one with the .xcodeproj file for a normal project) and run the following command:

```
curl -o .gitignore https://www.gitignore.io/api/swift
```

Or alternatively get it from the GitHub source:

```
curl -o .gitignore https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Swift.gitignore
```

You can edit the file to make changes if you need to. I just use the defaults.