# Xcode git can't ignore all *.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/ folders

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

I followed [cant-ignore-userinterfacestate-xcuserstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564257/cant-ignore-userinterfacestate-xcuserstate) and [ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository). But these never works.

My Step Reproduction:

1. Quit Xcode
2. project directory: `git rm -r --cached .`
3. project directory: `git add . && git commit -m "remove junk files"`
4. Open Xcode project
5. Then these files appear again.

Most troubled me was that each time I rebase code will automatic appear these files so I will rebase fail of unstage files. Each time I need to stash these file.

This is my .gitignore file code section:

```
### Xcode Patch ###
*.xcodeproj/*
!*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
!*.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/
!*.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
/*.gcno

*.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/
```

[image: source tree want to ignored files]

[image: my xcode project structure]

[image: this is a react-native project]

Comment: Please see _comments_ on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6565909/5306470 . Also, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437170/what-should-i-include-in-the-gitignore-file-for-swift-playgrounds

Answer (score 3):

I just realized that these `want to ignored` files was buried in deep folder.

And git don't support this kind of pattern `*.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/`.

Want to ignore other son son (recursive) folder need add this to .gitignore:

```
ios/**/*.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/
```

or a clean way:

```
**/xcuserdata/
```

This `**/*.xcodeproj` was git version 1.8.2's feature.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.16.1
```

So most of us can use it.

I learnt from [how-to-gitignore-files-recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550688/how-to-gitignore-files-recursively).